# seaborn kdeplot with hue returns error could not convert string to float: 'Female'

Tags: python, seaborn

Looking for help with seaborn `kdeplot`. I'm trying to follow the instructions in the seaborn `kdeplot` [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot) that use tips data. But I got the error of:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Female'.
```

when running the line

```py
sns.kdeplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="time")
```

Does anyone have any idea why this may happen? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50996623/10452700) and  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066158/10452700)? Can you provide us with your scripts?

Comment: Write the code you're using as a minimum reproducible example in the question and not in a link. This will make it easy for others to help.